# Capturing DV from MiniDV Camcorder via Firewire on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: firewire

**Edit:**

Yes, this should still work. I had two problems. 1) The camera I was using was junk (eBay is full of scammers selling old broken electronics as working), and 2) I needed to run `dvgrab` as root.

**Original Post:**

---

Is firewire capture from DV camcorders still supported? I've tried dvgrab and kino, and neither works.

Following the instructions [here](https://blog.jonsdocs.org.uk/2020/11/25/transferring-data-from-a-minidv-camcorder-using-linux/):

```
$ dvgrab --autosplit --format dv2 dvgrab-
Error: no camera exists
```

And running kino, when I click the "Capture" tab, I see this error on the bottom of the screen:

```
WARNING: raw1394 kernel module not loaded or failure to read/write /dev/raw1394!
```

If I run journalctl after plugging in the camcorder, I see this message, so it looks like the camera is detected:

```
Dec 10 13:58:54 jpc-linux kernel: firewire_core 0000:07:00.0: rediscovered device fw0
```

I tried running some firewire utilities to debug, but it looks like they can't even connect to the device.

```
$ dc1394_reset_bus 
libdc1394 error: No cameras found

$ testlibraw
successfully got handle
current generation number: 0
0 cards found

$ dumpiso
port: 0
channels: 0xffffffffffffffff
file: (null)
Port 0 does not exist.
```

Does anybody see what the problem is?